# How to automatically push cordova app to playstore

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, apk

I have build an app platform with PHP. 
it is creating apps using phonegap(cordova) and iconic. 
Now i need to automatically push created apps (apk)to playStore by php

Comment: So where are you stuck? The signing of the apk? The uploading? The authentication to the developer console? We're not mind readers.

Comment: Have created a google-play dev account? And why would you automated such thing?